# codefluent custom stored procedure

Tags: codefluent

I have a custom stored procedure with in parameters that return fields of different tables how I can map this custom stored to an entity? I only want to use like a read only values for a report I don't want to save or something like that I try to add the extra fields to the most similar entity but when I execute the method in code the extra fields are null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1: Using a view

A view allows to aggregate data from different entities.

```
<Article>
    <Id />
    <Name />
    <Lines typeName="LineCollection" />

    <cf:method name="LoadArticlesByCommand" body="load(string commandName) from ArticleByCommand where CommandName = @commandName" />

    <cf:view name="ArticleByCommand" autoLightweight="true">   
        <ArticleName expression="Name"/>
        <ArticleQty expression="Lines.Quantity" />
        <CommandName expression="Lines.Command.Name" />
    </cf:view>
</Article>

<Command>
    <Id />
    <Name />
    <Lines typeName="LineCollection" />
</Command>

<Line setType="List">
    <Article typeName="Article" key="true" />
    <Command typeName="Command" key="true" />
    <Quantity typeName="int" />
</Line>
```

- http://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/04/22/views-auto-lightweight-and-the-modeler/
- https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/Views_PersistentViews.html

## Solution 2: Using a lightweight entity

Instead of creating a view, you can can create a lightweight entity that contains only the properties used by the stored procedure.

```
<cf:entity name="Person" lightweight="true">
  <cf:property name="FirstName" typeName="string" />
  <cf:property name="lastName" typeName="string" />

  <cf:method name="ComputeBalance" 
             body="load () raw" 
             rawBody="SELECT 'John' AS FirstName, 'Doe' AS LastName" />
</cf:entity>
```

## Solution 3: Custom mapping

For more specific values or types, a custom method can be provided to map the database values to .NET types. This custom method will be called with a `DataReader` as parameter, meaning that a developer could do whatever he wants.

```
<cf:entity name="Sample">
  <cf:method name="LoadPair" body="raw" rawBody="SELECT 1234,5678" 
             returnTypeName="CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Pair&lt;System.Int32,System.Int32&gt;" 
             cfom:methodName="On{0}" />
  <cf:snippet>
    private static CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Pair&lt;int,int&gt; OnLoadPair(System.Data.IDataReader reader)
    {
        return new Pair&lt;int, int&gt;(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetInt32(1));
    }
   </cf:snippet>
</cf:entity>
```

You can also use `OnAfterReadRecord` or `OnBeforeReadRecord` rules

Answer (score 0):

If it is not essential that you map the results of the custom stored procedure to an entity than another option is to use the built in support for DataSets.

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/06/22/dataset-support-in-codefluent-entities/

```
<cf:method name="LoadAllCities" body="raw" returnTypeName="System.Data.DataSet">
SELECT $Address::City$ FROM $Address$
</cf:method>
```

.

```
DataSet ds = Address.LoadAllCities();
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("City: " + row[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-reading you're question I am providing another answer.

In response to the part where you said "I try to add the extra fields to the most similar entity but when I execute the method in code the extra fields are null". The following steps should be able to solve that problem.

1. Execute one of the automatically created stored procedure in SQL Management Studio.
2. Execute the stored procedure you manually created.
3. Verify that the fieldnames returned by both stored procedures match.

**I think the above will solve your immediate problem but I still don't like the solution.** The reason is that you said you picked the most similar entity. I think that is going to cause problems in the future especially if the stored procedure is not being mapped to all of the entities properties.

I would recommend either lightweight entity, view or DataSet.